# what is wrong with my python script to split the large size pdf into two and more parts?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, pdf, pypdf

I have a folder with multiple pdf files which has 10 MB to 250 MB more than that.
I try to write some python script to reduce the file size but un-fortunately I couldn't found any documentation on that. So, I try to split my Pdf one by one into 2 part for 20 MB file size for more than 20 MB file size split into more than 3 part and 4 or 6 part. so, I have a pdf with 100 MB file size of 375 pages.
I want to split it into 10 part that is 10 MB of each file size. Here I share my python script to split it into 2 part from pages number 0-175 is the first part and the second part is 176 to 375. after I run this script it says cannot assign to a literal.

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

pdf_file_path = 'Report_on_public_instruction_in_the_madras_presidency_1868_69.pdf'
file_base_name = pdf_file_path.replace('.pdf', '')

pdf = PdfFileReader(pdf_file_path)

pages = [0-175]
pdfWriter = PdfFileWriter()

for page_num in pages:
    pdfWriter.addPage(pdf.getPage(page_num))
    
with open('{0}_subset.pdf'.format(file_base_name), 'wb') as f:
    pdfWriter.write(f)
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run your script with no error. The problem though is your script will only return page#176 and add into your "file_base_name_subset.pdf" file.

- If you are splitting file, then you will need to initialize more than single PdfWriter object.
- You should consider using slice to breakup your pages.

```
for page_num in pdf.pages[:breakpage]:
    pdfWriter.addPage(page_num)
```

- You can also import pathlib modules to simplify your code instead of using the bult-in .open() function.
- By using the with Statement, you shouldn't have to call the .close() method at the end.